# Google web toolkit cannot build project

Tags: gwt

I've the following error when building my application with mvn package.

```
[DEBUG] Arguments: com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -war C:\ifrs9\ifrs9v2\Ifrs9-Web\target\Ifrs9 -workDir C:\ifrs9\ifrs9v2\Ifrs9-Web\target\gwt\work -deploy C:\ifrs9\ifrs9v2\Ifrs9-Web\target\gwt\deploy -sourceLevel 1.8 -failOnError -compileReport -XcompilerMetrics iason.ifrs9.web.client.Ifrs9EntryPoint
[INFO] Compiling module iason.ifrs9.web.client.Ifrs9EntryPoint
[INFO]    [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/andrea/.m2/repository/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/6.0/smartgwt-6.0.jar!/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.java'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 9335: Referencing method 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.FormItem.CustomStateGetter.getCustomState': method 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.FormItem.CustomStateGetter.getCustomState(Lcom/smartgwt/client/types/FormItemElementType;Ljava/lang/String;)' is deprecated
[INFO]    [WARN] Warnings in 'jar:file:/C:/Users/andrea/.m2/repository/com/smartgwt/smartgwt/6.0/smartgwt-6.0.jar!/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/calendar/Calendar.java'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 5226: Referencing deprecated class 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.events.CalendarEventMoved'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 5503: Referencing deprecated class 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.events.CalendarEventResized'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 6192: Referencing deprecated class 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.events.EventHoverHTMLEvent'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 7538: Referencing deprecated class 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.events.TimelineEventMoved'
[INFO]       [WARN] Line 7594: Referencing deprecated class 'com.smartgwt.client.widgets.calendar.events.TimelineEventResized'
[INFO]    Finding entry point classes
[INFO]       [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:15 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-26T10:12:26+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 57M/480M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-8:compile (default) on project Ifrs9-Web: GWT exited with status 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Could you please help me to solve this build error?

Comment: Hint: 
`[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly`

Comment: How can I fix the error?